# How to add php values to a function in a wordpress dashboard widget?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am working on a plugin for wordpress - and I am pretty new at this - but I am trying to make dashboard widgets that display feeds from different sources (CNN, The Onion, MOZ, etc.) I have the plugin set up with a custom options pages I got from https://jeremyhixon.com/tool/wordpress-option-page-generator/ and everything seems to work right. My question is - how do I take the values from the options page and add them to my widget code. Here are the specific options:

Feed Label
Feed URL
Number of Articles

```
    /* 
 * Retrieve this value with:
 * $dashboard_feeds_options = get_option( 'dashboard_feeds_option_name' ); // Array of All Options
 * $feed_label_0 = $dashboard_feeds_options['feed_label_0']; // Feed Label
 * $feed_url_1 = $dashboard_feeds_options['feed_url_1']; // Feed URL
 * $number_of_articles_2 = $dashboard_feeds_options['number_of_articles_2']; // Number of Articles
 */
```

Here is an example of my widget code with The Onion as a feed source

```
/** START The Onion Dashboard */

add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'onion_dashboard_add_widgets' );
function onion_dashboard_add_widgets() {
    wp_add_dashboard_widget( 'dw_dashboard_widget_onion', __( 'The Onion', 'dw' ), 'dw_dashboard_widget_onion_handler' );
}

function dw_dashboard_widget_onion_handler() {
    $feeds = array(
        array(
            'url'          => 'https://www.theonion.com/rss',
            'items'        =>15,
            'show_summary' => 1,
            'show_author'  => 0,
            'show_date'    => 1,

        ),

    );

    ob_start(); // start output buffering
    wp_dashboard_primary_output( 'dw_dashboard_widget_onion', $feeds );
    $buffer = ob_get_clean(); // get the buffer without printing the content

    // add the target attribute to the a-tag:
    $result = str_replace("<a class='rsswidget'",
                          "<a class='rsswidget' target='_blank'", $buffer);
    echo $result;
};

/** END The Onion Dashboard */
```

To sum it up - how do I take the values entered in the options page into this code to make it easy for someone to add multiple dashboard widgets to their site? As always - thank you in advance for helping me figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

I would use`get_option`, you can find more on it here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/.  The basic idea would be something like this:

```
// from your plugin

$example_option_value = get_option('example_option_key');

// do something with $example_option_value
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Mike - will give this a try today!